# Using GROUP BY to consolidate records from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

The 'data' for this follows -- there may be more or less rows of the source-table:

| UID_MOTRIP | UID_PERSON | UID_INSPECTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 413 | 14 | 77 |
| 411 | 17 | 0 |
| 407 | 16 | 74 |

I need to have a result that evaluates from the above table TO what shows in the following table.
The 'UID_INSPECTION' value of ZERO (for UID_MOTRIP=411) indicates that the inspection WAS NOT performed.  The 'InspectionCount' is where the 'UID_INSPECTION' value is > 0, meaning the inspection WAS PERFORMED. The 'UID_MOTRIP' represents the 'maximum' UID_MOTRIP value. This 'result' shall always be 1-row.

| UID_MOTRIP | InspectionCount | InspectionMissingCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 413 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: What have you tried? where did you get stuck?

Comment: Where is the relationship between these rows defined? As it stands, they appear to either all be related as they are rows in a table, but what would differentiate them from another entity?
As for counting the number of inspectionss, you can likely use a `CASE` expression: `CASE WHEN UID_INSPECTION = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS InspectionMissingCount, CASE WHEN UID_INSPECTION <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS InspectionCount`. This can then be aggregated how ever you need. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: But `407` is the minimum value in your data, not the maximum.

Comment: I tried using Group By on the source-table but I did not figure a way to 'Count()' where the ZERO UID_INSPECTION is 'counted' to 1 and the non-ZERO UID_INSPECTIONs is counted to 2 from the three source-records.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Define "Maximum": why the 407 row and not the 411 or 413 rows, which have greater values? Remember, **there is no such thing as table order!** The database is free to re-order those results anytime it feels circumstances warrant. This isn't common, _but it does happen_.  You can't just say to use the "last" row in the result without also defining _HOW_ the last row is determined.

Comment: The 407 is a typo -- it should be the MAXIMUM as you have pointed out.  I shall edit the question to replace 407 to 413.  Thank you all.

Comment: @PatrickHurst...The source-data/table is the result of an inline sub-query.  I have reduced the entire group of sub-queries to the last one that shows which 'trips' (UID_MOTRIP) and 'drivers' (UID_PERSON) performed or NOT an inspection for a vehicle.  There are many trips per day and this represents that three drivers had a chance to perform an inspection.  When an inspection is "inputted" by the driver, the UID_INSPECTION has a non-zero value.  The business rule is that the inspection is required on the driver's last trip of the day.  We are looking for the 'not-inspected' trips per driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is gonna be three separate `SELECT` queries nested inside the main statement. The trick is using **conditional aggregation** inside two of the queries:

```
SELECT
     (SELECT MAX(UID_MOTRIP) FROM [table]) UID_MOTRIP
   , (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN UID_INSPECTION > 0 THEN 1 END) FROM [table]) InspectionCount
   , (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN UID_INSPECTION = 0 THEN 1 END) FROM [table]) InspectionMissingCount
```

The problem is this really is three separate passes through the data. *We can do better.*

If there's a column in the table that **always** has the same value, you can `GROUP BY` that column and then do normal aggregation. This seems like an odd thing to happen, but it's actually common in vendor products with lots of configuration, where the vendor doesn't know in advance which columns you might need and the ones you don't use are left at some default value.

```
SELECT
     MAX(UID_MOTRIP) UID_MOTRIP
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN UID_INSPECTION > 0 THEN 1 END) InspectionCount
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN UID_INSPECTION = 0 THEN 1 END) InspectionMissingCount
FROM [table]
GROUP BY [common_column]
```

In this way, the database will do all the aggregation as it moves through the data in a single pass.

If you don't have such a column, you can project one:

```
SELECT
     MAX(UID_MOTRIP) UID_MOTRIP
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN UID_INSPECTION > 0 THEN 1 END) InspectionCount
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN UID_INSPECTION = 0 THEN 1 END) InspectionMissingCount
FROM (
   SELECT 0 as GroupColumn, UID_MOTRIP, UID_INSPECTION
   FROM [table]
) t
GROUP BY GroupColumn
```

This is slightly less-efficient because of the projection, but still likely to be an improvement over the basic option.

But if the performance matters here, I'd still TEST this vs the original, because the query optimization engine can sometimes surprise you.

Comment: The extraneous fake grouping column makes no sense. For a start. the compiler is going to optimize it away anyway. And you can do `GROUP BY ()` if you really want, but you could just as easily leave out the `GROUP BY` completely and use scalar aggregation.

Comment: I selected Joel's answer with GROUP BY ColumnGroup -- worked like a charm.  Thank all for responses.